# I need assistance with pinpointing a std run time error

Tags: c++

So the question above pretty much explains my problem, I have a program that prints the code size of my fragment shader and vertex shader, it is part of my Game engine project I have been working on for the past few days as a learning experience to get more knowledge of low-level c++ programming, but the problem is when I list where both shaders are placed in the project, my program proceeds to crash with a memory leak, the answer I need is exactly why this is happening

PipeLine.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace G_piplne
{
    class EdtrPipeLine
    {
    public:

        //grabs the file path to the frag file of the glsl shader file
        EdtrPipeLine(const std::string& vertFilePath, const std::string& fragFilePath);

    private:

        //gets the file path of both the frag file and vert file
        static std::vector<char> readFile(const std::string& filepath);

        //grabs the file path to the vert file of the glsl shader file
        void createGraphicsPipeLine(const std::string& vertFilePath, const std::string& fragFilePath);
        
        

        
        
        
    };
}
```

PipeLine.cpp used for initiating the functions in the PipeLine header file

```
#include "shaders_h/PipeLine.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace G_piplne
{

    EdtrPipeLine::EdtrPipeLine(const std::string& vertFilePath, const std::string& fragFilePath) 
    {
        createGraphicsPipeLine(vertFilePath, fragFilePath);
    }

    std::vector<char> EdtrPipeLine::readFile(const std::string& filepath)
    {
        std::ifstream file(filepath, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);

        if (!file.is_open()) 
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to open file: " + filepath);
        }

        size_t filesize = static_cast<size_t>(file.tellg());
        std::vector<char> buffer(filesize);

        file.seekg(0);
        file.read(buffer.data(), filesize);

        file.close();
        return buffer;

        
        
    }

    void EdtrPipeLine::createGraphicsPipeLine(const std::string& vertFilePath, const std::string& fragFilePath)
    {
        //Reads Frag and Vert Code Size
        auto vertCode = readFile(vertFilePath);
        auto fragCode = readFile(fragFilePath);

        //Prints Frag and Vert Code Size
        std::cout << "Vertex Shader Code Size: " << vertCode.size() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Frag Shader Code Size: " << fragCode.size() << "\n";

    }
}
```

and finally, the EditorConfigWindow header file which uses the function to display my vert and frag code size

```
#pragma once

#include "EditorWindow.h"
#include "../shaders_h/PipeLine.h"

namespace G_editor 
{

    class EditorWindowConfig
    {
    public:
        //Init Varibles for the size of the Editor Window
        static constexpr int WIDTH = 800;
        static constexpr int HEIGHT = 600;


        void run();

        private:
            //init Window with name GPRPG
            EditorWindow editorWindow{ WIDTH, HEIGHT, "GPRPG" };

            //Display vert and frag code size
            G_piplne::EdtrPipeLine edtrPipeLine{"../../Shaders/simpleShader.vert.spv ", "../../Shaders/simpleShader.frag.spv"};

    };

}
```

All shader files are in the right place and listed correctly, I double-checked the names and they are correct as well, the error is as listed below

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8F0154F69 in GPRPG.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x00000064240FEEA8.

this error is hit at the breakpoint right when the createGraphicsPipeLine function is called from the EditorWindowConfig Header file, I've tried moving the shader files around in the project but it leads to the same problem, thank you in advance for any assistance given that may point me in the right direction to solve this problem

Comment: Crashes are not memory leaks. A memory leak is if you allocate memory (with e.g. `new`) but don't free it (with `delete`).

Comment: Ok... it's an error, but it does not change my question much at all, i need assistance with the listed error above.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger to catch the exception? Or adding an exception handler to your code to print the exception message? I'm pretty sure that it's your own runtime error thats being thrown though.

Comment: Your program throws a runtime error if the file fails to open.  Check that the file exists and your program has permission to open it (_e.g._ it's not locked for read due to being open in some text editor), and if it's a relative path, check the working directory is what you think it is.

Comment: You throw a runtime error if it fails to open a file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In researching, I found that adding the absolute path to my shader file actually outputs the size as expected, the program didn't like the short path I was inputting for some reason